# Issue with aad-pod-identity and nmi on same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac, aad-pod-identity, nmi

i have a cluster where i have aad-pod-identity installed like the instructions found here:
https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/getting-started/installation/#helm
[image]

That seemed to work fine for the most part, but because of other issues i ended up running
az aks create -g myResourceGroup -n myAKSCluster --enable-pod-identity
as you find here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity

This seems to have installed an additional nmi, through a daemonset:
[image]

and because of this, i'm getting a CrashLoopBackOff from this nmi pod:
[image]

the logs say the issue is :

> error creating http server: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:2579: bind: address
> already in use

I've tried deleting the nmi daemonset, thinking that having that and the aad-pod-identity deploy might be the same thing done 2 different ways, but the daemonset keeps ressurecting somehow.  How do i clean up this issue?  Thanks